# Get the last data inserted in the DB in DRF

Tags: python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I am trying to get the last data inserted in the database of the particular user in django rest framework. I have wrote something like:

```
class UserSensorDeviceCount(generics.ListAPIView):
    authentication_classes = (authentication.TokenAuthentication,)
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)
    serializer_class = serializers.UserSensorDeviceSerializer

    def get(self,request,format=None):
        queryset = models.UserSensorDevice.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)
        notification = models.UserDeviceNotification.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)
        user_count = queryset.count()
        last_notification = notification.order_by('-id')[0]
        content = {'device_count':user_count, 'notification_count': notification.count(), 'last_notification':last_notification}
        return Response(content)
```

I am getting an error as

> Object of type UserDeviceNotification is not JSON serializable

I guess something I am doing wrong on getting the last notification. Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks !!

Comment: You are returning the whole object. If don't want to return a single field (like `notification.order_by('-id')[0].id`) from the `UserDeviceNotification` model, then you should use a serializer.

Comment: I have changed my answer, I only wanted the last message despite the complete object..

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this But not very sure this is the right way to do it.

```
class UserSensorDeviceCount(generics.ListAPIView):
    authentication_classes = (authentication.TokenAuthentication,)
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)
    serializer_class = serializers.UserSensorDeviceSerializer

    def get(self,request,format=None):
        queryset = models.UserSensorDevice.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)
        notification = models.UserDeviceNotification.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)
        notification1 = models.UserDeviceNotification.objects.filter(user=self.request.user).values()
        user_count = queryset.count()
        last_notification = notification1.order_by('-id')[0]['notification_msg']
        content = {'device_count':user_count, 'notification_count': notification.count(), 'last_notification':last_notification}
        return Response(content)
```

Answer (score 0):

Django model provides something called `latest` ( [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.latest) )

Your need is good example when this can be used. This will also handle a case when there is no notification.

I would implement your view in the following way

```
class UserSensorDeviceCount(generics.GenericAPIView):

    authentication_classes= (authentication.TokenAuthentication,)
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)
    serializer_class =  None

    def get_queryset(self):
        return models.UserDeviceCount.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        device_queryset = self.get_queryset()
        notif_queryset = models.UserDeviceNotification.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)

        return Response( data= {"device_count": device_queryset.count(),
                                "notification_count": notif_queryset.count(),
                                "latest_notification": NotificationSerializer(instance=notif_queryset.latest('id')).data },
                         status=200)
```